# CSS Select more span at once inside a class

Tags: css, selection

How can i select more span of the same class in CSS? I'd need it for hover specifically.

I tried with `span.classname:hover`
and `.classname span:hover`
where the first doesn't work at all, and the second one works only for one span at a time.

This is how the html looks:

Comment: Can you show us your code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `:hover` selector would apply to the span when it is being hovered over.

If you want to highlight all spans within an element when you hover on the element, you need to shift the `:hover` selector left:

```css
    div.special:hover span {
        color: red;
    }
```

```html
<div class="special">
    <span>Span</span> and another <span>Span</span>
</div>
```

This will apply to all spans inside the special div, when you hover over the special div.

If you want the other spans to activate when one span is hovered, you are going to have to script it... the closest you can get in CSS is the general sibling selector, which works on the span and other spans that follow it within the same parent. I would imagine you'd want it to work backwards too, which it doesn't in this case.

```css
span:hover, span:hover ~ span {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <span>Span</span> and another <span>Span</span>
</div>
```